# Why didn't this atomic swap go through?

Tags: atomic-swap

I attempted [swapping](https://github.com/comit-network/xmr-btc-swap) 0.01 of testnet BTC for stagenet XMR and BTC that
was meant to be swapped for XMR was refunded to me. When I executed
`swap buy-xmr --testnet --change-address tb1qf9p5mrl2mf4ulae257ewj2rns6hsu2y4p8j0q2 --receive-address 78Qb9HKw6CQGfLdnWQtBNXUkyeGvz3XeMHc59hs8CGe8TrMfUnsYqsLdHGng8Xs896TuCUxoKPwjP4DZ1Vebfm7WCMALwKF --seller /dnsaddr/unstoppableswap.net/p2p/12D3KooWLHbHtkK53WoBA82Yht3PCCx6KXYxoJ6QqgXg1rSNtWhR`
I got the following output from `swap`:

```
Connected to Alice at /dnsaddr/unstoppableswap.net/p2p/12D3KooWLHbHtkK53WoBA82Yht3PCCx6KXYxoJ6QqgXg1rSNtWhR
Received quote price=0.00605939 BTC minimum_amount=0.00010000 BTC maximum_amount=0.10000000 BTC
Waiting for Bitcoin deposit deposit_address=tb1q369qkpa6pxmg79qp6zatfnexka723z8hezv2ne max_giveable=0.00000000 BTC minimum_amount=0.00010000 BTC maximum_amount=0.10000000 BTC
Received Bitcoin new_balance=0.01000000 BTC max_giveable=0.00999875 BTC
Starting new swap amount=0.00999875 BTC fees=0.00000125 BTC swap_id=93b2db62-7032-4bd6-812a-7288db37e737
Estimated fee of 138.23298630 is smaller than the min relay fee, defaulting to min relay fee 1000
Estimated fee of 150.34098510 is smaller than the min relay fee, defaulting to min relay fee 1000
Published Bitcoin transaction txid=6ae82a171e25d85a317516078d6c4a25d34f7f4eee910bf247d7924400ba7a63 kind=lock
Waiting for Alice to lock Monero
Alice locked Monero txid=4b01a1e785ffb09090b336b76979f404f1f97a3995b7aeb6e356491ac84899c5
Waiting for Monero transaction finality txid=4b01a1e785ffb09090b336b76979f404f1f97a3995b7aeb6e356491ac84899c5 target_confirmations=10
Received new confirmation for Monero lock tx txid=4b01a1e785ffb09090b336b76979f404f1f97a3995b7aeb6e356491ac84899c5 seen_confirmations=1 needed_confirmations=10
Received new confirmation for Monero lock tx txid=4b01a1e785ffb09090b336b76979f404f1f97a3995b7aeb6e356491ac84899c5 seen_confirmations=2 needed_confirmations=10
Received new confirmation for Monero lock tx txid=4b01a1e785ffb09090b336b76979f404f1f97a3995b7aeb6e356491ac84899c5 seen_confirmations=3 needed_confirmations=10
Received new confirmation for Monero lock tx txid=4b01a1e785ffb09090b336b76979f404f1f97a3995b7aeb6e356491ac84899c5 seen_confirmations=5 needed_confirmations=10
Received new confirmation for Monero lock tx txid=4b01a1e785ffb09090b336b76979f404f1f97a3995b7aeb6e356491ac84899c5 seen_confirmations=6 needed_confirmations=10
Received new confirmation for Monero lock tx txid=4b01a1e785ffb09090b336b76979f404f1f97a3995b7aeb6e356491ac84899c5 seen_confirmations=7 needed_confirmations=10
Published Bitcoin transaction txid=94f18b0d37641e20ee57a679890437fbeeb6ee8dd9d66e97fdbf91ddb8c4d552 kind=refund
Waiting for Bitcoin transaction finality txid=94f18b0d37641e20ee57a679890437fbeeb6ee8dd9d66e97fdbf91ddb8c4d552 required_confirmation=2
Waiting for Bitcoin transaction finality txid=94f18b0d37641e20ee57a679890437fbeeb6ee8dd9d66e97fdbf91ddb8c4d552 seen_confirmations=1 needed_confirmations=2
Waiting for Bitcoin transaction finality txid=94f18b0d37641e20ee57a679890437fbeeb6ee8dd9d66e97fdbf91ddb8c4d552 seen_confirmations=3 needed_confirmations=2
```

The amount of BTC that
I've sent in both cases was within the accepted by the seller range, i.e.
0.00010000 - 0.10000000 BTC and the seller seemed to be online all the time.

`history` subcommand clearly shows that the swaps have not succeded:

```
+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
| SWAP ID                              | STATE             |
+==========================================================+
| 93b2db62-7032-4bd6-812a-7288db37e737 | Done: BtcRefunded |
|--------------------------------------+-------------------|
| ba633b45-5b09-4dcd-bc3a-71986d003893 | Done: BtcRefunded |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

This is [the transaction](https://mempool.space/testnet/tx/b4d3c66160dd160d2bcacc8a2f1cafc66ce5b4131cc6fc369a0420d84385419d) that initiated the swap. I've no clue why my swaps have not succeded.
Am I missing anything?